# How to select a specific cell in Google Sheets' QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

[image: screenshot here]

So I have named range called Profil. It is on another sheet. The "C" cell on that query is in Profil range. I want to set C parameter to start date (B3) end date (B4) cell, so the date is dynamically changed according to the start date and end date. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
=QUERY(Profil, "SELECT * WHERE C>=DATE'"&TEXT(B3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C<=DATE'"&TEXT(B4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

The query needs the date in a specific format (yyyy-mm-dd), this converts whatever is in cell B3 and B4 into that format and checks the less than / greater than formula.

Works for me:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote in your screenshot, but it generates error

Comment: Did you try copying the code I posted above? I adapted it to the screenshot in your question whereas the screenshot I provided was a simple example.

What is the error returned?

Answer (score 0):

try like this (with EU locale):

```
=QUERY(Profil; "where C >= date '"&TEXT(B3; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
                  and C <= date '"&TEXT(B4; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 1)
```